# How to insert many data from datagridview to database

Tags: c#, insert

I am adding multiple data through my datagridview named 'dgv'.
And I want save multiple data to my entities 'de' and database tabel 'DetailSPH2'.

But, when I save multiple data with "de.SaveChanges();" , It didn't work.
only one row in datagridview is being saved.

I already linq code below.

How to save all rows in my datagridview?

Please help me.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < dgv.RowCount; i++)
        {
            string KodeBarang = dgv.Rows[dgv.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
            string NamaBarang = dgv.Rows[dgv.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[1].Value.ToString();
            string Harga = dgv.Rows[dgv.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[2].Value.ToString();
            string JumlahPesananSPH = dgv.Rows[dgv.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[3].Value.ToString();
            string TotalPerBarang = dgv.Rows[dgv.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[4].Value.ToString();


            DetailSPH2 la = new DetailSPH2();
            la.NoSPH = txtNoSPH.Text;
            la.KodeBarang = KodeBarang;
            la.NamaBarang = NamaBarang;
            la.Harga = float.Parse(Harga);
            la.JumlahPesananSPH = int.Parse(JumlahPesananSPH);
            la.TotalPerBarang = float.Parse(TotalPerBarang);

            de.AddToDetailSPH2(la);

            de.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

With this line (and the following ones)

```
string KodeBarang = dgv.Rows[dgv.CurrentRow.Index].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

you take always the same `CurrentRow` and your loop repeats the insert with the same values.

You need to take the `Row` indexed by your loop variable `i`

```
string KodeBarang = dgv.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString();
```

and so on for the other variables